# MySQL - Select rows with approximate interval

Tags: mysql

I run a website dedicated to tracking statistics of players on an online game. One of the functions of the website is to build charts for them to track their progress over their past 2000 games.

What I'm currently doing is using this query to get all his records, then using PHP to select the records in increments of approximately 100 battles, until I have the 20 records I need to build the charts:

```
SELECT DISTINCT battles, victories, survived, destroyed, detected, 
       hitratio, damage, capture, defense, avg_exp, efficiency 
  FROM account_stats 
 WHERE account_id = XXXXXXX 
   AND battles >= ZZZZZZZ;
```

ZZZZZZZ is his current number of battles minus 2000. I'm using distinct because the database can keep duplicate values (this is because of some historical functions).

The reason I must use approximate values is because I get the data from the game's API, so during one check, he might have played multiple games. This means that in the database, the "battles" count will be of varying increments.

Using the query above is simply killing the database server since it creates a lot of temporary tables on disk, bringing the entire website to a crawl.

So my question is: Is there any way I can select exactly 20 rows in the database, selecting rows which are CLOSEST to 100 battles from the previous, without using DISTINCT / GROUP BY / anything that creates temporary tables on disk?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `LIMIT 20`? Hang on, I need to read the question a little more.